# type mismatch in scala when using reduce

Tags: scala, reduce, type-mismatch

Can anybody help me understand what's wrong with the code below?

```
case class Point(x: Double, y: Double)

def centroid(points: IndexedSeq[Point]): Point = {
  val x = points.reduce(_.x + _.x)
  val y = points.reduce(_.y + _.y)
  val len = points.length
  Point(x/len, y/len)
}
```

I get the error when I run it:

```
Error:(10, 30) type mismatch;
 found   : Double
 required: A$A145.this.Point
  val x = points.reduce(_.x + _.x)
                            ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`reduce`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.6/scala/collection/IndexedSeq.html#reduce[A1%3E:A](op:(A1,A1)=%3EA1):A1), in this case, takes a function of type `(Point, Point) => Point` and returns a `Point`.

One way to calculate the centroid:

```
case class Point(x: Double, y: Double)

def centroid(points: IndexedSeq[Point]): Point = {
  val x = points.map(_.x).sum
  val y = points.map(_.y).sum
  val len = points.length
  Point(x/len, y/len)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `reduce` you need to reduce both `x` and `y` in a single pass like this

```
def centroid(points: IndexedSeq[Point]): Point = {
  val p = points.reduce( (s, p) => Point(s.x + p.x, s.y + p.y) )
  val len = points.length

  Point(p.x/len, p.y/len)
}
```

If you want to compute `x` and `y` independently then use `foldLeft` rather than `reduce` like this

```
def centroid(points: IndexedSeq[Point]): Point = {
  val x = points.foldLeft(0.0)(_ + _.x)
  val y = points.foldLeft(0.0)(_ + _.y)
  val len = points.length

  Point(x/len, y/len)
}
```

This is perhaps clearer but does process the `points` twice so it may be marginally less efficient.